# Gelifying hydrogen peroxide

Tags: materials, mixtures, colloids

What substances could be used to gelify 60% hydrogen peroxide? I imagine anything organic like agar would be broken down by the radicals. I tried looking up what dentists use and the only thing that came up was glycerine, which I know from experience doesn't make gels with water, so I doubt it would work with $\ce{H2O2}.$

Comment: Dentists use what they call [carbamide peroxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_peroxide_-_urea) to avoid premature decomposition of the gel itself.

Comment: Since 60% H2O2 decomposition is *highly* exothermic and produces reactive oxygen rather violently, I'd question adding *anything* that might catalyze that reaction.